# CMake: How to avoid link error when the project contains .asm MASM sources with VS2013?

Tags: assembly, cmake

I'm using CMake 3.0.1 with "Visual Studio 12 2013" generator.

I added .asm files to a project. Then, the linker error LNK2026 has occurred when `cmake --build .`.

The LNK2026 error is *module unsafe for SAFESEH image*.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/100ezk17.aspx

If I add a project property manually as following, it works fine.

> <UseSafeExceptionHandlers>true</UseSafeExceptionHandlers>

Could I avoid the linker error without changing the generated project file?

Here is a simple project that cannot build with generated .vcxproj.

### a.c

```
extern void ExAsmCode();

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ExAsmCode();
    return 0;
}
```

### m.asm

```
.586
.model flat, c
MessageBoxA     proto STDCALL :dword, :dword, :dword, :dword

.data

MSG          DB 'masm', 0

.code

ExAsmCode PROC
    invoke MessageBoxA, 0, offset MSG, offset MSG, 0
    ret
ExAsmCode ENDP

end
```

### CMakeLists.txt

```
CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 3.0)

PROJECT(Ex)

ENABLE_LANGUAGE(ASM_MASM)

add_executable(Ex a.c m.asm)
```

Comment: You should include full error message. Not many people have all the LNK error messages memorized.

Comment: The msdn site link has been added because of I cannot get actual error message in English. Thanks.

Comment: @YasuoOhno i didn't have the experience with vs, but i want to ask would the function implementation in asm need name mangling?

Comment: .model directive tells to asselble the C naming and convention. So, the symbol ExAsmCode is transformed to _ExAsmCode automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `/safeseh` flag to source:

```
set_source_files_properties(
    my.asm
    PROPERTIES
    COMPILE_FLAGS "/safeseh"
)
```